# Gradle Build Dependencies in reverse

Tags: gradle

I have project D which depends on projects A, B and C.

If I build D, gradle builds A, B and C correctly.

I would like to know if I build A, can gradle builds D even A does not depend on D, but D depends on A.

As before project D depends A, B, and C. Publishing D is working fine. But Publishing A or B is trying to publish D, which I don't want to publish D. I am using following code to publish.

```
publishing.publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact source: "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar", extension: "jar"
        }
    }
```

I do build under root folder which has gradle build and execute following command for publishing:

```
./gradlew clean :projectA:build -x test publish
```

Comment: If your intention is to build D, why do you ask gradle to build A? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: The idea that someone can change A, B, C and that change might introduce a bug in D, by auto building D after building A, can catch the error.

Comment: OK. Then you can just build D, or use the buildDependants task on A after you've introduced the change in A. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1692C

Comment: Tks JB. I have another question. I build A only, no need to build D, but when trying to publish A using maven plugin, it is trying to publish D even though I did not build D and I don't want to publish D.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details: what is the structure of your project, how do you publish, etc.

Comment: Please check original question about publishing issue.

Comment: Please format the code as code, explain where this code is located, and tell how you publish (i.e. which command do you execute, from which directory, etc.)

Comment: I have root project which has A, B, C and D. I am running under root project.  ./gradlew clean :projectA:build -x test publish

Comment: So you run publish on the root project, which thus calls publish on all the subprojects. If you want to publish A only, it should be `./gradlew :projectA:publish`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

To build all projects that depend on A, you can use

```
./gradlew :A:buildDependants
```

To only publish A, you must run

```
./gradlew :A:publish
```